# Angular Strap. Popover programmatic use

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I'm trying to create programmatically popover, but faced with following problem. I can't access parent scope inside popover template. Expected result is:

```
Hello my name is Roman
```

but I get

```
Hello my name is undefined
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOpg3rDW2vKk2hd1Z6FT?p=preview)

If I use `bs-popover` as attribute on any element, then I get expected result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Popover issue</title>
</head>

<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="defaultCtrl" style="margin: 100px 100px">
    <button custom-popover ng-click="showPopover()">Popover</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="example.html">
        <p>My name is {{user.name || 'undefined' }}</p>
    </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.min.js" data-semver="1.3.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.5/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.5/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ngSanitize']);
    app.controller("defaultCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
            name: "Roman"
        };
    }]);
    app.directive("customPopover", ["$popover", "$compile", function($popover, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var myPopover = $popover(element, {
                    title: 'My Title',
                    contentTemplate: 'example.html',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    autoClose: true
                });
                scope.showPopover = function() {
                    myPopover.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout http://plnkr.co/edit/62BDv7JwluOl3eqtXPCZ?p=preview

Prototype inheritance is default on scope in angular.

So if you are not creating isolated scope then you can access parent scope objects from your scope directly until and unless you are not overriding them.

```
 var myPopover = $popover(element, {
                    title: 'My Title',
                    contentTemplate: 'example.html',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    autoClose: true,
                    scope: scope
                });
                scope.showPopover = function() {
                    myPopover.show();
                }
```

Comment: Great, thank you, but why this option (scope) is not [documented](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers#popovers-usage) ?

Comment: Yeah, it's not there in documentation. But in code $popover uses $tooltip internally. There is one line in $tooltip provider   `var scope = $tooltip.$scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new();` . So if you pass scope in your option, it will create a new scope from it. Else it will create new scope from rootscope.

Comment: OK. Next time I will check the source code before post a question.